# Latitude e5470 no Print screen button

Tags: display, printing

There is no Print screen button in my laptop. Can I assign somehow this function? Or is there a way to do it?

Comment: VTC because this is essentially a product recommendation request. If you can be a bit more specific about your requirements and environment (e.g., operating system), you might be able to get a response in [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: @JeffZeitlin It's a problem-based question where software may be a solution. [These are valid according to our guidelines](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14725/194694). I agree that specifying the OS would be a good idea, but it's most likely Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following example script will map <kbd>F12</kbd>
to the missing PrintScreen key:

```
F12::Send {PrintScreen}
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Dell Latitude E5470 does have a Print Screen key. It's in the top row, between <kbd>F12</kbd> and <kbd>Insert</kbd>. It's labeled <kbd>PrtScr</kbd>. It can be labeled differently on localized keyboards.

It's possible that you have the top row configured to work with their secondary ("blue") functions by default. In that case primary functions like Print Screen will be a accessible by holding the <kbd>Fn</kbd> button while pressing the key. This behavior can be toggled permanently by pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>.

A physical Pause/Break key is missing from the keyboard, but it can be emulated by pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. No software or drivers are required for this to work.

Comment: Where PrtScr key is supposed to be a Druck key is and it brings Laptop at Flight mode

Comment: @ZPap It's the same key. You have a German keyboard layout, _Druck_ is short for _Drucken_ which means _Print_. With your settings, keys will work with their "blue functions" by default and you have to press them together with `Fn` to get the basic behavior.

Comment: I tried it and all that was happening was going to Flight mode. Solved it with a .ahk file. Thank you guys